# Removing one object from multiple ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to make it so that, by deleting one object from one ArrayList, it deletes it from all the other ArrayLists that it exists in?

So for example in the code below, if I deleted everything from the ArrayList `fives`, the ArrayList `test1` would contain no `NumHolder`s that contained the value 5.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    ArrayList<NumHolder> test1 = new ArrayList<NumHolder>();
    ArrayList<Five> fives = new ArrayList<Five>();
    String all = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++){
        NumHolder number = new NumHolder(i);
        test1.add(number);
        if(i%5==0){
            fives.add(number);
        }
    for (int j = 0; j < fives.size();j++){
        fives.remove(0);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < test1.size();j++){
        test1.get(j).toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a weird question. Just because if NumHolder and Five are the same object or other objects, aren't these array list just holding Integers? You could have a collections of collections, but it does seem weird to do this because it seems that NumHolder and Five might have different objects. Definitely possibly as mentioned in the answer, but maybe a better data structure could be used if you could explain if there is a applicable purpose to this.

Answer (score 0):

its easier than that my friend, just don't add the number numbers that divides on  5 without a reminder to your `test1` `ArrayList`.

```
 ArrayList<NumHolder> test1 = new ArrayList<NumHolder>();
    ArrayList<Five> fives = new ArrayList<Five>();
    String all = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++){
        NumHolder number = new NumHolder(i);
        if(i%5==0){
            fives.add(number);
            continue;
        }
        test1.add(number); 
      }
    for (int j = 0; j < fives.size();j++){
        fives.remove(0);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < test1.size();j++){
        test1.get(j).toString();
    }
```

Comment: That whole loop at the end actually is equivalent to a single call to `fives.clear();` - it doesn't just remove the same element N times; as each element is removes, the others are shifted, so it removes each successive element.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is, instead of removing your elements from `fives`, keep them in that list and use the list in a single call on all the other lists:

```
test1.removeAll(fives);
```

If you don't want that - if there are too many lists and you don't want to call removeAll() on each list, and you really want all lists to *share* the elements, then you could wrap the elements in a class that contains a single member variable. Then set the member variable in the wrapper to null, instead of deleting it. Then all lists will be referring to the same wrapper element whose contained value was set to null.

Comment: Is that how I would have to do it if i wanted the items to be "linked" by that I mean that when I delete one instance from one list lets say NumHolder(10) from test1 that then fives wouldnt have a NumHolder(10)?

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. Your NumHolder class would have to be made to hold an Integer instead of an int. They would also have to be given a setter, so that you can change the object they hold. Then, instead of deleting the element from the list, you hold call numHolder.set(null). Then all your lists would still contain this holder, but it will hold null. When you iterate through each list, you will have to skip all numholders that hold null. Alternatively, have NumHolder hold an int, but also add a boolean to it, indicating whether it's empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all 5s from both lists just use:

```
test1.removeAll(fives);
fives.clear();
```